# ZipZap filename issue

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, zipzap

I have been playing around with the zipzap framework and i'm having trouble calling the      fileName Property. I am able to unzip files with my current set up but i can not name them. This is one way i called it from my program

```
let archive: ZZArchive = ZZArchive(URL:(fileURLWithPath:PathToZip!), error: &err)
println(archive.entries[0].fileName)
```

I am getting the error

'fileName()' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of OS X 10.9 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

/AppKit.NSDocument:9:24: 'fileName()' has been explicitly marked unavailable here

Link to the documentation:

http://pixelglow.github.io/zipzap/api/Classes/ZZArchiveEntry.html#//api/name/fileName

Link to the framework:

https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to forcedowncast but this fixed the issue.

```
let archive: ZZArchive = ZZArchive(URL:(fileURLWithPath:PathToZip!), error: &err)
var currentent = archive.entries[1] as ZZArchiveEntry
println(currentent.fileName)
```

Comment: That's the right approach. Unfortunately the compiler can't know that the `entries` array contains a `ZZArchiveEntry` at that index and not a `NSDocument`.